# MySQL Count and Group By two distinct columns

Tags: mysql, database, group-by

I have a table `recommendation` with fields `recommender`, `attractionid`

I want to count the how many `attractionid` existed in the table group by the `attractionid` but if there are same pairs of `recommender` and `attractionid` they are counted as 1.
For example,

```
attractionid    recommender
      1               1
      1               2
      1               1
      2               3
      2               1
      2               2
      2               2
      2               2
```

expected result :

```
 attractionid   count
      1            2
      2            3
```

the rows below should be counted as 1

```
 attractionid    recommender
          1               1
          1               1
          2               2
          2               2
          2               2
```

Comment: for `attractionid = 2` `cnt must be 3` isn't? (`recommender 1, 2, 3`)

Comment: Yes you are right. Thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `distinct attractionid,recommender` inside `count` function.

**Query**

```
select attractionid,
count(distinct attractionid,recommender) as `count`
from recommendation
group by attractionid;
```

Comment: It works too! since this does not require subquery I accepted this as the answer. thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
select attractionid, count(recommender) cnt
from (
    select distinct attractionid, recommender
    from recommendation
) x
group by attractionid
```